# Broken Image Icon and TypeError: comments.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]this is my code and it has 2 issues. First is the image in the following code is not displayed and shown by broken image icon and the second is **TypeError: comments.map is not a function** this error.

```
import React from 'react';


function RenderComments(comments){
     if (comments != null)
            return(
                console.log(comments),
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    <h4>Comments</h4>
                    <ul className="list-unstyled">
                            {comments.map((comment) => {
                                return (
                                    <div key={comment.id}>
                                        <li>
                                        <p>{comment.comment}</p>
                                        <p>{comment.rating} stars</p>
                                        <p>-- {comment.author} , {new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day:'2-digit'}).format(new Date(Date.parse(comment.updatedAt.toDate())))}</p>
                                        </li>
                                    </div>
                                );
                            })}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            );
        else
            return(
                <div></div>
            );
}

function FullPost (props){
        return(
                <>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <img src={props.post.image} height="100" width="100" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <h3><strong>{props.post.title}</strong></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <h4>--{props.post.author}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <p>{props.post.content}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row ">
                            <RenderComments comments={props.comments}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            );
}

export default FullPost;
```

Also when i console log the comments, it correctly displays an array of comments so no problem there.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just console log the comments somewhere. It is not an array. Regarding the image - check what is inside ```props.post.image```  Probably the URL is not correct

Comment: @Drag13 Hey, I have the **console.log(comments)** screenshot, would you mind looking at it and suggesting changes. Thanks .

Comment: It's an array as I see. You also did the check for null. So the last point is to check how do you pass props to the ```FullPost (props)```

Comment: @Drag13 Anything about the broken image? the **assests** folder is in the screenshot show is in the public folder but still **{post.image}** is crashing.

Comment: Let's fix the issue one by one. If comments are not an array, might be images are also passed wrongly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Image problem

You didn't provide the shape of the `post` prop, you've got to make sure that  `post.image` represents a valid url to the resource. If the resouce is provided from local assets and the path is relative (it lives inside your project and the relative path from root is being passed in `post.image`), then it should be properly imported into your component:

```
<img src={require(props.post.image)} height="100" width="100" />
```

But with this approach you would have to ensure that `post.image` is an absolute path to the resource.

2. `.map() is not a function`

You are trying to call the prototype method `map` on a data which is not an array. Just make sure that it's being called when `comments` is guaranteed to be an array type:

```js
// ...
if (Array.isArray(comments)) {
    return // map the comments
}
return <div/>;
```

Your current condition `comments != null` just checks if it's any other type than null, so more specificity is needed.

Comment: hello sir, I have added the **console.log(comments)** screenshot to clarify that props.comments is an Array. Would you mind looking at it and suggesting chnages?

Comment: Did you try to change the condition to the one I've suggested? I understand that the comments in moment of logging is an array, however depends on where you placed the logger, the value you get from it might be deceiving and you might still omit an instance where `commits` is not an array. You could also try to change the logic to `comments && comments.length > 0`